# Annotation based hibernate mapping for external classes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mapping

Is it possible to provide annotation based hibernate mapping informations for external classes?

I have a model class (for example Credit) in an external package (without any dependencies to hibernate) which I can't / wan't edit and now I wan´t to define mapping informations for this class.

It's no problem to define these mapping informations in a xml file but I am looking for a possibility to define these informations via annotations.

I can extend the model class but then the child class is mapped but i wan't to map the superclass.

Comment: No there isn't, not if you cannot modify the class. Use xml instead.

Comment: So bad... thanks for your help